# What's the canonical way to get individual stream size in a video file?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, multimedia

I have a video file. It contains a video stream, and a couple of audio and subtitle streams.

**I want to get the size of each of these streams.**

---

I've already looked at `ffprobe`/`avprobe` and `mediainfo`, to no avail. Is there a way to obtain this from the command line that **doesn't require** to perform "real work" on the file (i.e. no transcoding, no stream extraction, etc.)?

Comment: I'm wanting to do the same thing and I'm curious, what does the "no avail" part of your question mean? Are all those tools unable to get individual stream sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=duration -select_streams a:n -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 -sexagesimal <input file>
```

Replace n with stream number.
It tells length of the nth audio stream. Use it without ":" like this `... -select_streams a -of ...`  and it will tell length of all audio stream. Replace a with `v` and `s` to get the length of video and subtitles. Use none and it will tell length of every stream.

Sources:

1. [Getting length](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/16356)
2. [Selecting stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47572950/11621646)

Edit:

Not noticed, it is already solved in Video SE, in [first link's accepted answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/16359)